# android Style dropdown of ActionBar

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-actionbar, background-color

Currently I am working on a little android app. I try to change the background color of the `ActionBar`'s dropdown menu. So far I was only able to change the background color of the `ActionBar` itself, but not of the dropdown menu. It simply does not change the color. Here is some code from my `styles.xml`:

```js
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"></style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/MyActionDropDownStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/background_color_action_bar</item>
    <item name="background">@color/background_color_action_bar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionDropDownStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@color/background_color_action_bar</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/background_color_action_bar</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/background_color_action_bar</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@color/background_color_action_bar</item>
</style>
```

The MyActionBarStyle part works but the MyActionDropDownStyle does not. I suppose that the parent of MyActionDropDownStyle might be wrong. Maybe someone of you has an idea and can help me.

Thanks in advance!